# How do I set the Apache2 DocumentRoot to a "vboxsf" VirtualBox Shared Folder? (permissions issue?)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, apache-http-server

I setup Ubuntu 11.04 desktop 32 bit on a VirtualBox VM with a shared folder to the host. The shared folder is

```
/media/sf_Dev/
```

I want to change Apache2 to point the `DocumentRoot` to that folder, so I edited `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` to replace the existing **two** paths in that file to /media/sf_Dev/ instead of /var/www and it won't show index.html.

When I look at `/var` with `ls -l` I see

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root ... www
```

and when I `ls -l /media/` I see

```
drwxrwx---  1 root vboxsf ... sf_Dev
```

and Apache doesn't seem to see the index.html I put in that directory (`cp /var/www/index.html /media/sf_Dev/` iirc)

I also tried editing envvars to make the group be vboxsf but I think I did that part wrong.

```
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

to

```
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=vboxsf
```

What am I doing wrong, what do I need to do to get Apache2 to serve files from that directory? (technically I want to serve files for apache from `/media/sf_Dev/apache/www` but I figure one step at a time, so if that helps you short-circuit things, so be it)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It would probably be easiest to add the vboxsf group as a supplementary group for apache.

Ubuntu:

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf www-data
```

Fedora:

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf apache
```

This does it for me when I want to access auto mounted shared folders. You might also want to add your own username to the vboxsf group to access the files.

Comment: But is the apache app running under the username apache? I thought that changed >.>

Comment: You're correct, I mixed the apache user for fedora and ubuntu. edited :)

Comment: Saved me a bunch of time fiddling around with manual mounting.. thanks!

Comment: This solution fixed it for me on Ubuntu 15. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a permissions issue.  You'll need read and execute permission on `/media/sf_Dev/` for "other" (the third group of permission bits, which are currently no permissions or `---`).

So, you'll need to run this command (since it's Ubuntu, note the sudo):

`sudo chmod 775 /media/sf_Dev/`

That will add read and execute for "other" and leave full permissions for owner and group.

Also make sure that the index file actually exists in /media/sf_Dev/.  (I'll assume that you forgot the sudo in the cp command and that you're not running as root.)

Comment: Ahhh, but when I do _that_ it doesn't make the changes I need. Something about the vboxfs doesn't let those changes get made (ie: like NFTS) ... oooh, which may be the problem, the files are originally hosted on NTFS (since it's a windows host) so I don't think I _can_ do that. ~~ I had forgotten to look at the errorlog before asking. I shall check that this evening. However, assume it's a permissions error.

Comment: @jcolebrand Rule #1 of troubleshooting: is it plugged in?  Nevermind that I'm thinking about the long term usefulness of the answer and that I know you as a DB and .NET guy. :P

Comment: @jcolebrand So, silly question: Did you restart apache?  `sudo apache2ctl restart`

Comment: hahahahaha, this is why I need help, I'm a db and .net guy ;) ... yeah, I actually dropped into `sudo su` once it started being a wench so I could go into all the directories and see what was "broken" ... I'm gonna do what Josh suggested later with the PHP file.

Comment: I did a graceful, not a restart. Big difference? Also, tonight it'll have a cold-restart (VM, full shutdown both boxes)

Comment: @jcolebrand  Well, there are some differences.  On a dev system, I would use restart.  There is no reason to (potentially) complicate things by using graceful:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/stopping.html

Comment: It is possible that vboxsf does not support setting permissions for the root folder of file system and it may provide mode, uid and gid mount options to set file permissions globally.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say what the specific error was, only

> and Apache doesn't seem to see the index.html I put in that directory

The specific error would help. You can file this in Apache's `error_log`, which is typically under `/var/log/apache2/error.log` under Ubunt, but can be configured via an [`ErrorLog` Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errorlog) in your `<VirtualHost>`

Without the actual error, I assume George Marian is correct and it's a permissions error. You can check to see what group Apache is running under using:

```
ps -o pid,group -o atime,comm=CMD awx | grep apache
```

Try chainging permissions on `/media/sf_Dev/` as he said.

I think you may better off handling this with an [Alias directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) as that will allow you to make only certain parts of your DocumentRoot point to locations outside:

```
Alias /info /media/sf_Dev
<Directory /media/sf_Dev >
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**EDIT:** If the Apache server has `mod_php` (not FastCGI PHP) and is not using `suexec`, you can determine if Apache is running under the proper GID (group ID) with the following PHP snippit:

```
<?php

var_dump(posix_getegid());
```

Make sure that returns the same GID as `vboxsf`. (You can find the GID for vboxsf in `/etc/groups`)

Comment: I had forgotten to look at the errorlog before asking. I shall check that this evening. However, assume it's a permissions error. See my response to George above

Comment: OK. Then we should focus on getting Apache to run as GID `vboxsf`. Can you edit and post the relevant parts where you changed the `Group`?

Comment: I edited one line in envvars, and it said group, but I'm not looking at the box right now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have configured the shared folder to be auto mounted. Then you need to first disable the same and mount the shared folder manually. If you need automount it every time you start the vm, you need to add respective entry inside your /etc/fstab. (It seems there is some issue mounting vbox shared folder through fstab. So adding below mentioned command inside /etc/rc.local worked for me to mount it on start).

#### Load Shared Folder with Correct User / Group

As far as I can tell, this error is due to the owner and group of the shared folder. Apache expects the files to render to belong to the group www-data. By default, however, the shared folder in VirtualBox belongs to the vboxsf user. We will add this user to the www-data group. To do so, edit the group properties on the guest:

`sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf www-data`

We’ll now mount the shared folder and assign it to the www-data user and group. To check out the user and group id, you can have a look at the /etc/passwd file on the guest machine (cat /etc/passwd | grep 'www-data'). On Debian based OS, both ids are usually set to the value 33. So, simply issue the following command on the guest:

`mount -t vboxsf -o rw,uid=33,gid=33 website /media/sf_website`

Note that website is the name of the shared folder (as illustrated in the screenshot above) and /media/sf_website is where the folder will be mounted.

Fore more details refer this link http://jimmybonney.com/articles/configure_virtualbox_shared_folder_apache_virtual_host/