# Execute PHP files in mounted directory from VirtualBox host system is not working

Tags: linux, virtualbox, apache-http-server, mount, php

I've set up a VirtualBox with a Debian 6.0 to act as a webserver. The host machine is my PowerBook running OS X 10.7.3.

Under `/User/cb0/Sites` I have a webproject in symfony that I used to develop under OS X.

Now I've mounted that directory to `/var/www/host-sites` in the virtual machine, so I have a environment that's exacly like the production enviroment.

The problem is php won't execute files in the mounted directory for some reason. When I call `index.php` I get a white page, no error message neither in frontend nor in any apache/system logs.

If I create a file with `phpinfo();` in a non shared directory, and then executing this via CLI or web browser, I get the desired output.

However when I call the same file in the shared directory I get no output.

The mounted filesystem is read/writeable and this works fine. Even static files are delivered correctly. It's only php that doesn't do anything.

Does someone have a clue what could be the problem?

I've already followed this advice which helped me a lot: [How do I set the Apache2 DocumentRoot to a "vboxsf" VirtualBox Shared Folder? (permissions issue?)](https://superuser.com/questions/335322/how-do-i-set-the-apache2-documentroot-to-a-vboxsf-virtualbox-shared-folder-p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by reinstalling the VB Guest Addon.

This post https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=15679 explains quite in detail how to do that.

pbr answer is also a good idea if you have any related problem.

This is my rc.local now:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o rw,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000 Sites /var/www/host-sites/
```

Comment: For me what actually fixes it is switching to the version shipped with VirtualBox, not reinstalling in and of itself. The version that ships with VirtualBox 4.2.12 works but `virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms=3.2.10-dfsg-1+squeeze1` in the Debian Squeeze repo doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Check the options on the mount.  Is "noexec" enabled?

Comment: Exec was enabled. I just solved the problem by reinstalling the Virtual Box Guest Addon for my Kernel Version. Thanks